# node js exec command not work when copy mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, child-process

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const exec_string = 'cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin mysqldump --user=xyz --password=xyz --host=localhost mydb| mysql --user=xyz --password=xyz --host=localhost newdb';
exec(exec_string, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log("error >>",error);
  console.log("stdout >>",stdout);
  console.log("stderr >>",stderr);
});
```

Here i want exec_string using nodejs exec command.
when i run this code some error display.

```
SyntaxError: Invalid hexadecimal escape sequence
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Comment: You should install mysql and ensure you can run `mysql` on the command line.

Comment: i can't run direct mysql in my cmd. i go for this path **cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin** after can run mysql on cmd.@JohnKennedy

Comment: I want to copy one of my database to a new database where , there i have name and connection credentials for both. So what else can be done in order   to achieve this? @JohnKennedy

Comment: You should add mysql to the path environment variables so you can simply run `mysql` on cmd